# JPA 2.0 & EJB 3.1 - update the owner side relationship was trying to insert record?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have a model:

```
@Entity
class A {
   @ManyToOne
   B b;
   int i;
}

@Entity
class B {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="b")
   List< A > list = new ArrayList< A >();
}
```

Now in my EJB service I do:

```
void f(Aid,Bid){
   A a = em.find(A.class, Aid);
   B b = em.find(B.class, Bid);
   a.setB(b);
}
```

This throw db constraint exception (INSERT INTO B VALUES... WITH SAME VALUES THAT ALREADY EXIST IN CURRENT B).

1. Why it's try to insert a new record to B while it's already exist in B table and the relationship is not PERSIST?

NOTES:

1 When i do after the last row:

```
em.merge(a);
```

It's work as well...???

2 When i do `a.setI(1)`; without merge - it's changed in DB (like i thought it will)

THANKS!!!

Comment: Your question is really confusing.  What are you asking?

Comment: Can you provide more information on your model like id properties etc?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bidirectional relationship. You should always update both sides of the relations ships. Otherwise, if you don't directly have problems while persisting, you can easily corrupt your cache and face some stange bugs in your application.

So, if you have this:

```
A a = em.find(A.class, Aid);
B b = em.find(B.class, Bid);
a.setB(b);
```

You should add this right after:

```
List<A> aList = b.getList();
if (!aList.contains(b)) {
    aList.add(b);
}
```

> 2 When i do a.setI(1); without merge -
>   it's changed in DB (like i thought it
>   will)

If you're using an entityManager in an ejb (which I seems you do regarding your tags), it's normal that changes to managed entities are persisted. Was that te question?

Also, you should make sure that entities identity, equals() and hashcode() are defined correctly (maybe it is, but you didn't mention it).